# Get reponse from nodejs request

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to get the response of one request in nodeJS, but I cant get it yet. Can you help me please? This is the code:

```
var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://api.web.com/v1/prospects?search=12345&api-key=123456',
    'headers': {
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error)throw new Error(error);
    var result =  response.body;
});

console.log(result);
```

and this is what I got:

```
(node:14848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: result is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because result is not defined in the scope you are using it.

```js
let result;
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error)throw new Error(error);
    result =  response.body;
});

console.log(result);
```

However, even this doesn't make sense, because the `request` call is asynchronous, and `result` will not be set when using in the `console.log`. You probably want:

```js
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    const result = response.body;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!! is there any way to use the result even out of the scope?

Comment: Well, you could, like I showed, make the scope be outside of the callback. But the question is how you will know whether or not the variable is ready to be used. But yes, you could.